# Creating multiple nodes in a

Tags: neo4j

What would be the proper way to load the following structure from the [Neo4j Tutorial](https://neo4j.com/developer/graph-db-vs-rdbms/)?

[image]

The way I have it now is to first `CREATE` Alice with a department and then add on the other two, referring to Alice now as a variable so it doesn't re-create that Node:

```
create (p:Person {name:"Alice"})-[:WORKS_AT]->(d1:Department {name: "4FUTURE"})
create (p)-[:WORKS_AT]->(d2:Department {name: "PO815"})
create (p)-[:WORKS_AT]->(d3:Department {name: "A42"})
RETURN p,d1,d2,d3
```

Is this the suggested way to do it, or is there perhaps a more straightforward way to do it, such as:

```
create (p:Person {name:"Alice"})-[:WORKS_AT]->(d1:Department {name: "4FUTURE"}, 
                                               d2:Department {name: "P0815"}, 
                                               d3:Department {name: "A42"})
```

---

I suppose perhaps this is the most straightforward way?

```
CREATE (p:Person{name:"Alice"}),(d1:Department{name:"D1"}),(d2:Department{name:"D2"}),
(d3:Department{name:"D3"}),(p)-[:WORKS_AT]->(d1),(p)-[:WORKS_AT]->(d2),(p)-[:WORKS_AT]->(d3)
RETURN *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way would be

```
CREATE (p:Person{name:"Alice"})
UNWIND ["4FUTURE", "P0815", "A42"] as d
CREATE (d:Department{name:d})
CREATE (p)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(d)
```

And perhaps also use MERGE instead of CREATE.